# After install/uninstall KDE

Tags: gnome, kde, 21.04

I'm under Ubuntu 21.04. I tried KDE using KDE-desktop package.

After a little try, I remove it. But then, my Ubuntu doesnt gnome normally

I'm stuck before I could log in (with the motherboard manufacturer logo). I have to start in rescue mode, then resume start (it will start without gpu or something). Then I could log in in CLI mode, then use `startx`

Do you have any ideas what I broke ?

Thanks

Comment: Try running `sudo systemctl set-default graphical` from a command line then see if that allows for your GUI to start up automatically after a reboot.  Speaking from personal experiences, chances are you might have to reinstall the OS since KDE can really embed itself into the OS and destroy other Desktop Environments.

Comment: I have the following error `Failed to set default target: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)` 
Yes I think I'll have to reinstall OS, but I want to try to avoid that, because I'm scared of GRUB after that ahah (i have windows installed in another ssd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found something :

I install lightdm : `sudo apt install lightdm` and choose lightdm as default

I reboot, and magic, it works ! :)

I just remove and reinstall gdm3 after, to retrieve the default 21.04 Display Manager :)